# Responsive Horizontal Layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a horizontal layout with width: auto and height: 100%, but the body or container doesn't stretch to keep the aspect ration of my image.

I need the layout to be like this seen in this attached image:

[image]

I will use these images as a background of the panel divs.

Here is my code:

HTML

```
 <body>
      <div id="cover" class="panel">
      <img src=""/>
      </div>
      <div id="panel1" class="panel">
      <img src=""/>
      </div>
      <div id="panel2" class="panel">
      <img src=""/>
      </div>
      <div id="panel3" class="panel">
      <img src=""/>
      </div>
      <div id="panel4" class="panel">
      <img src=""/>
      </div>
 </body>
```

CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
}

.panel {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
}

.panel img {
    width: auto;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: -1;
}
```

You can also see it at this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamthestig/rsPRz/).

I floated the .panel to the left so it will display it all horizontally, but the container is not accomodating the width of all the panels, they just stack on top of each other.

Note: I don't want to have a fixed with, I need it to be responsive.

Here's an example of what I want to accomplish ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/iamthestig/cJUQa/)).

As you can see there's no vertical scrollbar only the horizontal scrollbar is showing and when you resize the viewport the images adjust its width and height and keeps its aspect ratio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an update of your original fiddle: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rsPRz/45/

Trying to stay as close to your original code as possible...

### HTML

```
<html>
<body>
    <img src="http://i978.photobucket.com/albums/ae265/horizoncars/lambo-cover.jpg"
    /><img src="http://i978.photobucket.com/albums/ae265/horizoncars/lambo-left-2.jpg"
    /><img src="http://i978.photobucket.com/albums/ae265/horizoncars/lambo-left-1.jpg"
    /><img src="http://i978.photobucket.com/albums/ae265/horizoncars/lambo-right-1.jpg"
    /><img src="http://i978.photobucket.com/albums/ae265/horizoncars/lambo-right-2.jpg"/>
</body>
</html>
```

### CSS

```css
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    overflow-x: scroll;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    white-space:nowrap;
}

img {
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Yes! But, there's no more containing div in the img. I need a div there because i have to put some text in there.

Comment: It will work the same with a container, but the particulars will depend on where you are adding the text and whether the text is supposed to move with the images. Can you give an example?

Comment: Hi David, thanks for this. But can you please see what I'm doing wrong in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/iamthestig/69kgt/? I want to overlap the #cover-section in this fiddle to the image.

Comment: Here's an update where I positioned the text absolutely. http://jsfiddle.net/69kgt/15/

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to keep all of them in a parent div whose width and height will be equal to the window width and height

Comment: No. I don't want them to fit in the browser's width. I want the body to accommodate the width of all the images.

Comment: i.e. if there are 4 images of 1000px, you want to show them on the screen at one time?

Comment: No. I want them to show one at a time, when the user scrolls horizontally. i.e the image is 1280 x 800, if the browser size is 1600 X 900 the image must resize to to accomodate the larger screen size keeping their aspect ratio. Like my example here: jsfiddle.net/iamthestig/cJUQa

Comment: I'm sorry that is not my goal... i want them to be in there true aspect ratio, not distorted aspect ratio like in your example. Please see the layout image I attached. It has to be scroll-able.

Comment: Ok it's close to what I mean. But there is a spacing now between the images. Can you make it without spacing? I have new jsfiddle with another approach. I'll post it when it's done. I'm really glad you know javascript, cause I'm just starting in javascript. Thanks for helping me, really appreciate it.

Comment: Ok here's my new approach http://jsfiddle.net/iamthestig/gguka/
If you can add a script that will get the width of the 3 images and add them up then apply it to the #container's width.

Answer (score 0):

The example you have shown is working fine because it has single image. When you are using multiple images/div you should divide the width equally for the div and give `max-width:100%` to the image in it.

I have used only 4 divs for example. Check this demo http://jsfiddle.net/rsPRz/34/

Comment: In your example the container div will just fit the browser window, the horizontal scrolling is now off. I want it to be scrollable. The individual divs must have the width and height of the img inside them and keeping their aspect ratio. If you can float left the divs in this example: http://jsfiddle.net/iamthestig/rsPRz/

Answer (score 0):

With a `div.container` and a little help of jQuery you might get along.

Updated link: http://jsfiddle.net/rsPRz/37/

```
widthSum = 0;
$('.panel img').each(function() {
   widthSum += $(this).width(); 
});
$('.container').width(widthSum);
```

Is this a possible solution for you?

Comment: If you need the layout to adjust on window resize as well, you'd have to wrap the js code into a function and add a callback similar to this `$(window).resize(function(){ adjustLayout();});`

Comment: The problem is there are spacing between the divs.

Comment: The spacing only occurs after window resizing, right? At least in my chrome browser, that's the case. I added a callback for this case: http://jsfiddle.net/rsPRz/46/ You can still see some flickering while resizing, but I think one might still call it responsive though.

Comment: It's weird when the browser is resized the horizontal layout would break and there would be a vertical scroll and the images is stacked on top of each other.

Comment: Hm, weird indeed. Just tested that last link in Chrome, Firefox and Safari and it seems to work here. But maybe David Kolar's answer is the way to go, as it doesn't require any javascript.